# Creating counter columns dynamically through a java module

Tags: cassandra, hector

I want to create countercolumns in a column family. Creating column family and counter columns (and indexes if need) need to be done dynamically. I need a java code to do this. Can I do this with hector or any other method?? plz send me helpful links ..

Answer (score 2):

Counter column families are supported in Kundera post release 2.0.7. For details, visit:

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Cassandra-Specific-Features

Answer (score 1):

Here are the relevant links I found:

1. https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Examples
2. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.hector.user/4723
3. http://pastebin.com/ixPX3fwq
4. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.hector.user/4705
5. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/hector-users/EtY46VjsbM0
6. https://github.com/rantav/hector/blob/master/core/src/test/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/model/MutatorTest.java#L214
7. https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/tree/kundera-2.0.7/kundera-cassandra/src/test/java/com/impetus/client/crud/countercolumns
8. https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/5c05d118e22eef541a7a201adf7c1c610da13f5b/src/test/java/com/netflix/astyanax/thrift/ThrifeKeyspaceImplTest.java